# Bit shift and convert character to unicode escape string

Tags: java, hex, bit

I found a java class that convert byte or char to hexadecimal value. But I cannot understand the code clearly. Can you explain what the code do or where I can find more resources about this?

```
public class UnicodeFormatter {

    static public String byteToHex(byte b) {
        // Returns hex String representation of byte b
        char hexDigit[] = {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
            '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
        };
        char[] array = {hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f]};
        return new String(array);
    }

    static public String charToHex(char c) {
        // Returns hex String representation of char c
        byte hi = (byte) (c >>> 8);
        byte lo = (byte) (c & 0xff);
        return byteToHex(hi) + byteToHex(lo);
    }
} // class
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest.. but >> does a bit shift by however many digits. So b>>4 divides by 2^4 (or 16).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let us start with some definitions:

- A **`char`**, in Java, occupies **2 bytes**;
- Each **`byte`** is composed by **8 bits**;
- Each **hexadecimal** digit represents **4** binary digits or **bits**;

Therefore, a **`byte`** can be represented by **2 hexadecimal** digits, i.e., two groups of 4 bits. This is exactly what is being done in the `byteToHex` method: it firsts splits the byte in two groups of 4 bits, and then maps each into an hexadecimal symbol, using the `hexDigit` array. Since the decimal value of each group of 4 bits can never be greater or equal than 16 (`2^4`), each group will always have a mapping in the `hexDigits` array.

For example, suppose you want to convert the number `29` to hexadecimal:

1. `29` is represented in binary as `00011101`;
2. Splitting `00011101` in two groups of 4 bits yields `0001` and `1101`;
3. Programatically, the first group, `0001` can be obtained by shifting away the least significant 4 bits (`1101`) from the binary representation of `29`. Then, `0001` would become the first `4` bits. This is accomplished in Java with (`b >> 4`);
4. The second group, is obtained by `b & 0x0f`, which is equivalent to `00011101 & 00001111 = 00001101 = 1101`. By bit-`AND`ing the binary number with `0x0f` you are clearing (setting to 0) everything except the least significant 4 bits.
5. Finally, each group is converted to a decimal number, yielding `1` (`0001`) and `13` (`1101`), which are then mapped to `1` and `D` respectively, in the hexadecimal system.
6. The number `29` is therefore represented by `1D` in hexadecimal.

A similar logic can be applied to the method `charToHex`. The only difference is instead of converting a single byte, you are converting 2, since a `char` is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what it is doing here is the same as turning 23 into a string by changing it to 2*10+3, then turning 2 and 3 into characters.

To break it down, we first divide by 16, since we're working in hex.

b >> 4 means shift the bits 4 spaces, so

```
12345678 >> 4 = 00001234
```

then the value in positions 1234 get looked up in the hexDigit array.

Then we do a modulus operation, also known as getting the remainder.  In the decimal example, this is finding the 3 by chopping off everything to the left.  For binary, they are using AND here.

0x0f in bits is 00001111, so when ANDed with a byte, it will change the left 4 spaces into 0s, leaving only the right 4.

```
12345678 & 0x0f = 00005678
```

and again we look up the value in positions 5678 in the hexDigit array.  Note that I'm using 1-8 as position markers, the actual data will be all 0s and 1s.

Edit:  The second function does basically the same operation, it uses the same >>> and & functions to split the unicode char into bytes.  It appears to be assuming the unicode character is 16 bits, so it shifts it 8 places to get the left 8 bits, and uses & 0xff to get the right 8 bits.

Comment: I think "byte" are just 0 & 1, how you can shift 12345678?

Comment: See note that I was using 1-8 as position markers.  The actual data is all 0s and 1s.

Comment: Do you know why it has two part, I guess they are high and low? @Thomas

Comment: The unicode character has multiple parts because 2^8 is not enough characters for certain languages, so depending on the encoding it could have 16 or 32 bits.  Because a byte has 8 bits, it needs to be split for byteToHex to work on it.